# Appending HTML+RDFa with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, rdfa

My JavaScript script is not allowing to be marked up semantically. As you can see in my script below, I am using Schema.org and RDFa.

The problem is that when I validate my page, only the part before the `append` function is validated. This means that only type, headline, publisher and datePublished comes up.

How can I fix it? I suspect the problem here is the `append` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                        $.getJSON(webhose_request, function(results){ //send request to API and store results in "results"
                            //parse the results' from the JSON response and display them //in a div element for example <div class='webhoseapi'></div>
                            //we can loop to display all results in a for loop or using the results.posts.lenght; or just display a few.

                            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                // you need to read the JSON results to know how to parse them, for example here results.posts[i].text
                             var articletext = results.posts[i].text;
                              // we use regular expressions REGEX to replace any new line '\n' and carriage return '\r' with html breaks </br>
                              articletext = articletext.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '</br>');
                                $(".webhose").append('<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeOf="Article"><div property="headline" class="whtitel">'+results.posts[i].thread.title_full.substring(0,110)+'</div><div class="source"><b>Source:</b><span property="publisher"> '+results.posts[i].thread.site+'</span></div></div>');
                                if(results.posts[i].thread.author){
                                    $(".webhose").append('<div class="whpublished"><b>By:</b> <span property ="author">'+results.posts[i].thread.author+'</span></div>');
                                }
                                $(".webhose").append('<div class="whpublished"><b>Date published:</b><em><span property="datePublished"> '+results.posts[i].thread.published.substring(0,10)+'</p></span></em> </div>');
                                //we check if there is an image for this posts then display
                                if(results.posts[i].thread.main_image){
                                    $(".webhose").append('<div class="whimage"><img property="image" src="'+results.posts[i].thread.main_image+'" height="125" width="200"/></div>');
                                }
                                $(".webhose").append('<div property="articleBody" class="wharttext">'+articletext.substr(0,500)+'... <div class="whlink"><a property="url" href= '+results.posts[i].thread.url+'> Read full article »</a></div></div><br>');
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: There's a risk that the inserted text will break the html you create. It should be encoded. How are you testing this? Most validators are not very good with rendering JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that most of the parts of the article aren't in the `<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeOf="Article">` element. This can be shown to be true if one indents HTML from the first append:

```
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeOf="Article">
  <div property="headline" class="whtitel">'+results.posts[i].thread.title_full.substring(0,110)+'</div>
  <div class="source"><b>Source:</b><span property="publisher"> '+results.posts[i].thread.site+'</span></div>
</div>
```

In the following I have changed the code to create the article div and then append the contents to it and then append it to the document. The following is untested but I think it might work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON(webhose_request, function(results) { //send request to API and store results in "results"
    //parse the results' from the JSON response and display them //in a div element for example <div class='webhoseapi'></div>
    //we can loop to display all results in a for loop or using the results.posts.lenght; or just display a few.

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      // you need to read the JSON results to know how to parse them, for example here results.posts[i].text
      var articletext = results.posts[i].text;
      // we use regular expressions REGEX to replace any new line '\n' and carriage return '\r' with html breaks </br>
      articletext = articletext.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '</br>');

      var article = $('<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeOf="Article"></div>');

      article.append('<div property="headline" class="whtitel">' + results.posts[i].thread.title_full.substring(0, 110) + '</div>')
      article.append('<div class="source"><b>Source:</b><span property="publisher"> ' + results.posts[i].thread.site + '</span></div>');)
      if (results.posts[i].thread.author) {
        article.append('<div class="whpublished"><b>By:</b> <span property ="author">' + results.posts[i].thread.author + '</span></div>');
      }
      article.append('<div class="whpublished"><b>Date published:</b><em><span property="datePublished"> ' + results.posts[i].thread.published.substring(0, 10) + '</p></span></em> </div>');
      //we check if there is an image for this posts then display
      if (results.posts[i].thread.main_image) {
        article.append('<div class="whimage"><img property="image" src="' + results.posts[i].thread.main_image + '" height="125" width="200"/></div>');
      }
      article.append('<div property="articleBody" class="wharttext">' + articletext.substr(0, 500) + '... <div class="whlink"><a property="url" href= ' + results.posts[i].thread.url + '> Read full article »</a></div></div><br>');

      $(".webhose").append(article);
    }
  });
});
```